# Sybase 'select count' not showing up properly, trying to compare two tables

Tags: compare, sybase

I'm doing a count from table1 whose records/rows don't exist in table2

Here is the query:

```
select count(1) from table1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where
                  table1.col1 = table2.col1
                  and table2.id=1)
```

I need to see the records that are missing in table2 , whose id in table2=1, and these records should be available in table1. The PK here is col1.

The query returns me 0. But if I do an excel sheet comparing by removing both the tables to excel. I can find 1591 records that are missing from table1 and are available in table2.

Comment: Is this [tag:sybase-asa], [tag:sybase-ase], [tag:sybase-iq], or [tag:sqlanywhere]? Trying to clean up the [tag:sybase] tag...

Answer (score 0):

Your query is working fine.

You query finds records that EXISTS in `table1` but not in `table2`

You have found with excel records that does NOT EXISTS in `table1` and EXISTS in `table2`

If you'd like to find these records with SQL than your query should be:

```
select count(1) from table2 
where table2.id=1 and table2.col1 not in (select col1 from table1)
```

or with not exists version of this query:

```
select count(1) from table2 
where table2.id=1 and 
      not exists (select 1 from table1 where table1.col1=table2.col1)
```

I didn't test the queries.